# NSPredicate with AND and OR issues

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, core-data

I have the following NSPredicate:

```
 fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"url = %@ AND type = %@ OR type = %@", newsStory.url, [NSNumber numberWithInt:StoryHighlighted], [NSNumber numberWithInt:StorySavedAndHighlighted]];
```

I wanted to fetch a story with this particular URL and type of (highlighted or highlightedandsaved). However the query above doesn't seem to work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As simple as wrapping your OR in brackets to save any confusion?

```
fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"url = %@ AND (type = %@ OR type = %@)", newsStory.url, [NSNumber numberWithInt:StoryHighlighted], [NSNumber numberWithInt:StorySavedAndHighlighted]];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to do this:

```
fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"url = '%@' AND( type = %@ OR type = %@"), newsStory.url, [NSNumber numberWithInt:StoryHighlighted], [NSNumber numberWithInt:StorySavedAndHighlighted]];
```