# AND and OR combined with NSPredicate. IOS Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, core-data

A dynamic `or` predicate for my coredata `get` query

```
    var predicate = [NSPredicate]()
    //this three is or
        predicate.append(NSPredicate(format: "item_parent_id = %i", 1))
        predicate.append(NSPredicate(format: "item_parent_id = %i", 3))       
        predicate.append(NSPredicate(format: "item_parent_id = %i", 5))

    // but this one is and
        predicate.append(NSPredicate(format: "price_date CONTAINS[cd] %@", 'timestamp'))

    var compound = NSCompoundPredicate.orPredicateWithSubpredicates(predicate)
```

the first three constraint is for OR operator and the last constraint for date is AND

I spent quite time for this, I am new in swift development and I'm not used to Objective C , that is why I'm having a hard time translating to swift what I found written in objective c.

if possible write the answer in swift , any comment and suggestion would be a big help. THanks in advance

[obj c - source #1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10317692/combining-and-and-or-condition-in-nspredicate) 
[obj c - source #2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13593721/nspredicate-with-and-and-or-issues)

Comment: The "OR" part could be simplified to a single predicate `NSPredicate(format: "item_parent_id IN %@", [1, 3, 5])` ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're looking for an operation like `(a OR b OR c) AND d`, you need two compound predicates:

```
var orList = [NSPredicate]()
//this three is or
orList.append(NSPredicate(format: "item_parent_id = %i", 1))
orList.append(NSPredicate(format: "item_parent_id = %i", 3))       
orList.append(NSPredicate(format: "item_parent_id = %i", 5))
let orPredicate = NSCompoundPredicate.orPredicateWithSubpredicates(orList)

// but this one is and
let other = NSPredicate(format: "price_date CONTAINS[cd] %@", 'timestamp')

let compound = NSCompoundPredicate.andPredicateWithSubpredicates([orPredicate, other])
```

Comment: woah, i never thought this was so simple, I'll try it..thanks sir